# How to enable ssl using .Net 6 Web API, NGINX, OpenSSL?

Tags: c#, nginx, ssl, asp.net-web-api, openssl

How to enable ssl using .Net 6 Web API, NGINX, OpenSSL?

I created the Certificates using OpenSSL, these certificates are working with my Blazor Wasm App, so the certificates are ok. If I run the API over a http configuration on port 80 the API runs as expected, so API is also ok.

Running the API throws the following error message:

> Aborted
> root@TEST:/var/www/TEST/api# ./TEST_Web_API
> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
> To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https –trust'.

This is my NGINX configuration:

```
server {
listen 444 ssl;

server_name test.fritz.box;

ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx.key;

location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;   
}}
server {
  #Working Blazor wasm app
  listen 443 ssl default_server;

  server_name test.fritz.box;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx.key; 

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.demo.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.demo.log;

  root /var/www/test;
  index index.html;}
```

This is my API setup:

```
string _MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    //allow CORS    
    options.AddPolicy(_MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:444","http://localhost:81", "http://localhost:5000")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));  
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    //Raspberry PI

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.Urls.Add("http://192.168.178.51:5000");
    app.Urls.Add("http://localhost:5000");        
}

app.UseCors(_MyAllowSpecificOrigins);//Do not change the position of app.UseCors, the order is important! 

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

I guess something in the API configuration is wrong. What's wrong here?

Comment: try https://www.easydynamics.com/securing-an-asp-net-core-app-on-ubuntu-using-nginx-and-docker-part-iii/   and/or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: It is unclear what `./TEST_Web_API` is doing so it is unclear what the error message means and therefore unclear on how to solve the problem.

Comment: ./TEST_Web_API starts the web api. But the api is not executable for certificate issues.

Comment: Now I added my API setup via code snippet. The code block functions does not work with my code.

Comment: TLS (which replaces SSL) is performed before the HTTP request is sent.  The client when using HTTPS send a TLS request to server.  The server than send back a TLS certificate block which contains names of possible certificates.  The client than look up the names to certificate in the stores to find match certificate.  Your error indicates the certificate was not loaded in the stores.  Are you getting error in Windows or Linux?  Latest version of Net uses Windows for TLS.  OpenSSL is not used on a window machine, but is compatible with the Windows TLS.  OpenSSL is used on Linux.

Comment: I got this error on Linux Ubuntu. As I mentioned, I got this error only by running my API, my Blazor SPA worked as expected using SSL on 443. Do I have a problem with the port 444, or does the reverse proxy causes the problem?